# End a call before the receiver unhook

Tags: android, sip

I've made my own SIP client for Android. I'm facing an issue. I've made the test on SipDroid : if I call someone and hang up before he unhooked, the call end of the both side.
With my client, when I hang up, the call is not ended for the receiver, leading to a communication on one side.

Here is my code for ending a call :

```
if (call != null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to end call");

        try
        {
            call.endCall();
        }
        catch (SipException e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service failed to end the call", e);
        }

        call.close();

        updateStatus("Call Ended");
    }
```

Where call is a SipAudioCall.
I get my call like this :
    call = manager.makeAudioCall(profile.getUriString(), sipAddressToCall, listener, _Params.callWait);

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your API, but the SIP protocol itself has the "CANCEL" request to "hang up" before the call is answered.

On a normal, ongoing call, you send "BYE".

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to send request with the native SIP Android API